# unity (c#) and php password handling

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I have a website where users can create an account, the password is hashed with `SHA256` and all the info stored in a database.

I have a game made with `unity3d`, where the player have to login.

I used the WWW class to reach and get information from a login page of my website (of course no direct acces to the database). But I have to pass the username and password as POST values...

Now I have two question :

- I've read that I should use the php password library instead of SHA256, is that really critical?
- How can I login in the game without compromising security?

Comment: Is the user already logged in and then you pass them over to the game or what? Also yes SHA256 by itself probably isn't the most secure way to go about doing things

Comment: sha256 is not encryption its hashing.

Comment: @Pseudonym No, the game have a login form, that sends the username and password as POST values of an URL. Just as if it was a login form from the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link [here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm):

> If you're a web developer, you've probably had to make a user account
>   system. The most important aspect of a user account system is how user
>   passwords are protected. User account databases are hacked frequently,
>   so you absolutely must do something to protect your users' passwords
>   if your website is ever breached. The best way to protect passwords is
>   to employ salted password hashing. This page will explain why it's
>   done the way it is.

It will give you the basics of how to securely send, store, and use a password in php and even provides tested source code for you to use. **Please** do not try and come up with your own homebrew solution, use what this resource and make sure you understand it if you want to make your login secure.

Comment: In facts, I already use global salt + user salt and everything.. The problem is that I don't know how to be sure that I have the same hash method in both php and C#... As I red I should use password_hash in php, but how do I make a equivalent in C#?

Comment: that site should have a equivalent source code example for ASP.Net/C#